# Android: making emptyView invisible?

Tags: android, listview

I have a 2 list view and I switch between them by making one visible and one invisible.

They both have emptyViews that show when the listView is empty. However, I dont want the emptyView to show if the view is set to invisible regardless of whether it is empty or not.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***You can remove `empty` `TextView` from layout. If you don't want, you can do it by pragmatically as***

```
TextView empty = getListView().getEmptyView();
empty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: The format Ive used is like this:

`TextView groupEmptyText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emptyGroupText);

groupsView.setEmptyView(groupEmptyText);`

How can I set it to gone from that?

Comment: Ok then you can set visibility like `groupEmptyText.setVisibility(View.GONE);`  OR can use like `groupsView.setEmptyView(null);`.

Comment: And my answered code will also work (if you call given code after `groupsView.setEmptyView(groupEmptyText)` )